# Using getItemViewType() - How do I know which layout is 0 and which is 1?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm overriding the `getItemViewType()` method in my project to indicate which view to use for items in my list, `R.layout.listview_item_product_complete` or `R.layout.listview_item_product_inprocess`

I know this function must return a value between 0 and 1 less than the number of possible views, in my case 0 or 1.

How do I know which layout is 0 and which is 1? I presume the first layout I created will be 0 and the latter one 1, but I want to return a variable so that this value is flexible...

I.e.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Define a way to determine which layout to use
    if(//test for inprocess){ 
        return INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX;
    } else { 
        return COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX;
    }
}
```

What/where can I reference to define the values for `COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX` and `INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX` ?

Comment: "How do I know which layout is 0 and which is 1?" This depends on your data, what distinguishes a row that is "complete" or "inprocess"? (We cannot see your data...)

Comment: (I just noticed your comment from your previous question. Andy was notified by default because you commented on his answer, however I wasn't tagged with `@Sam` so I didn't get a notification...)

Comment: @Sam Oh yea I understand that. I just made up those 2 variable names. I dont know how to define them. I made a listview and added 2 layouts, named above. How do I pragmatically identify their indexes in the array that holds them? (Thanks for the tip about replying to someone via @ ) :)

Comment: You are asking for the code that goes here: `if(/* test for inprocess */)`, right?

Comment: No I need to know how to define `COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX` as 1 or 0. Seems like such a trivial thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know how to define COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX as 1 or 0. Seems like such a trivial thing!

Honestly, it doesn't matter whether `COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX` is 0 and `INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX` is 1, or vica versa. But you define them as class variables, in this case they can be `static` and `final` as well:

```
public class MyAdapter ... {
    private static final int COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_LAYOUTS = 2;

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            if(getItemViewType(position) == COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_product_complete, null);
            else // must be INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_product_inprocess, null);

            // etc, etc...
            // Depending on what is different in your layouts, 
            //   you may need update your ViewHolder and more of getView()
        }

        // Load data that changes on each row, might need to check index type here too
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Order thisOrder = (Order) myOrders.getOrderList().get(position);

        if(thisOrder.getOrderStatus().equals("Complete")) return COMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX;
        else return INCOMPLETE_TYPE_INDEX;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return NUMBER_OF_LAYOUTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: But to the OS, doesnt `R.layout.listview_item_product_inprocess` correspond specifically to 0 or 1? likewise with `R.layout.listview_item_product_complete` ? I thought i needed to figure out which index in the array holding these layout objects has each layout.

Comment: This is all you need to do, by overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` the recycler will handle the rest of the work.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you're saying... So in theory, I could implement the logic behind `getItemViewType()` within the `getView()` function. But the OS may use this function as well, so I need to define it. So within that function, how can I to the `//test for inprocess` piece? I would need to inspect an attribute for the view in question at `position`, correct?

Comment: "But the OS may use this function as well, so I need to define it." **Correct,** if you skip this the view recycler just won't work. "How can I to the `//test for inprocess` piece?" Your adapter needs to determine whether this row is 'complete' or 'inprocess' from the data driving the adapter. Depending on the adapter's type you might use `getItem(position)` to test which index type this row is.

Comment: Alright I think I've got that part. Now, what if convertView is not null, but its the wrong type? Will the OS handle that situation and not pass the wrong type of convertView to getView?

Comment: The recycler should sort which type of View is loaded on its own, so you shouldn't worry about it. (I haven't been able to reproduce what Andy was talking about... So I still think that his trouble is with his code.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt responses! I have updated your answer to include my functions. Look like what you had in mind?

Comment: No trouble! That will work great from what I can tell. Did you ever accept an answer to the previous question?

Answer (score 1):

in your `getView` method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 if(getItemViewType(position) == INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX){

//inflate a layout file
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.R.layout.listview_item_product_inprocess);
}

else{
{

//inflate a layout file
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_product_complete);

}

return convertView;
```

Comment: Yea, thats what I plan to do. I just dont know how to define INPROCESS_TYPE_INDEX. I just made those variables up for this example, but I need to assign them 0 or 1 correctly.